# Got a B1/B2 but never went for the trip. Can I use it to go later?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, change-purpose-of-travel

When working for my previous company, I got a B1/B2 US visa to go for an event in the US. But the trip got postponed and I moved to a different company soon after so I never ended up going. I now want to visit the US for tourism. I got the visa in 2016 and it's valid. I'm from India.